# When signing 2 GB XML file SignedXml.ComputeSignature throwing out of memory exception in 64 bit windows with 8 GB RAM

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net

I am trying to sign a 2 GB XML file using SignedXml.ComputeSignature however i am getting out of memory exception. I am using 64 bit machine with 8 GB RAM.It may be because of the file size. While computing the signature the function loads whole XML file into the memory. Do we have any alternative ay to sign an XML file. Is it possible in to sign XML file in chucks or stream.

Comment: .NET has an object size limit.  I think the limit is 2 GB.

Comment: You using a 64 bit machine, but is your application also in 64 bit? You can check this in the properties dialog (dont use "any CPU" use "x64").

Comment: Is xml suited for such large files?

Comment: i am using X64 platform

Comment: 2Gb XML ... I think you need to revisit whatever you're doing architecturally.  That sounds like a nightmare in the making.

Comment: its a requirement from the auditor. We need to write whole database into XML file.

Comment: If xml is mandatory even if it's not a good format for very large documents, can you, at least, split into several xml chunks, in separate files?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you on .NET 4.5?
If so try this:

[gcAllowVeryLargeObjects](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh285054%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: In practice the limit is more like 1.4 GB.   In theory you should be able to read a file in chunks and sign it.

Comment: In .net we don't have any method that signs file in chunks. Do you know any library that sign XML in chunks

Comment: No I don't know of any.  I said in theory.

Comment: Thanks for your help it worked with 4.5. It is slow it took 2 days for it but at least its working.